# How do I display fractions in a Django App?

Tags: html, xhtml

I am trying to display fractions on a website. I need them to add different dimensions for products and i do that in the django admin. I wrote a template tag, which you can see here. It works on firefox, but not on other browsers.
I appreciate any help on this. Thank you in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRowC.png

Comment: this is an html/css issue

Comment: @SuperStew Almost right.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very simple.

Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math

You'll see the support and all relevant info concerning this HTML tag and anything else in the HTML specification you care to search for in Mozillas excellent docs.